# method to find and search files JAVA

Tags: java

I need help with a method that finds a specific file and then prints out a line of text from that file. The line of text is printed if the string typed in the console matches a string from that line of text. For example if I were to call `java Find ring report.txt address.txt Homework.java` it should print something like:

`report.txt: has broken up an internationa ring of DVD bootleggers that`

`address.txt: Kris Kringle, North Pole`

`address.txt: Homer Simpson, Springfield`

`Homework.java: String file name;`

The specified word is always the first command line argument.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Code for E11.8. Searches all files specified on the command line and prints out all lines     
  containing a specified word.
 * @Michael Goedken
 */
public class Find
{
   /**
      Searches file for a word, prints out all lines containing that word.
      @param wordToFind the word to find
      @param filename the filename for the file to search
   */
   public static void findAndPrint(String wordToFind, String filename)
   {
   String input = args[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
   {
       System.out.println(" File  " + args[i]);
        File one = new File(args[i]);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(one);

        while (in.hasNext())
       {
           String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(input))
            {
               System.out.println(line);
            }
       }
   }


}

   /**
      First argument of the main method should be the word to be searched
      For other arguments of the main method, store the file names to be examined
   */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   // call findAndPrint for each text file



   }
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @pruntlar syntax error no variable for `args`

Comment: You're trying to read `args[0]` in your `findAndPrint` method ; that could work in `main` since it has an `String[] args` parameter, but it doesn't make sense in the context of your `findAndPrint` method.

Comment: @Aaron how can I change my method so that I can simply call `findAndPrint` in my `main` without moving the code to `main`

Comment: Your search word is `ring`. Suppose a file has the following line: _"A diamond ring is worth a thousand dollars."_ What would be the output?

Comment: @Aaron could I change `args` to the `wordToFind` parameter?

Comment: @progyammer the output would be "A diamond ring is worth a thousand dollars" since it has the word 'ring" in that line

Comment: Might be best to delete this question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I think I get your issue now.

You can call your method from the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//may need to throw file not found exception here
        findAndPrint();
    }
```

Then you need to remove the arguments from your method:

```
public static void findAndPrint() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\yourfilepath\\actualfile.txt"));
        //you can get user input etc here if necessary
        String input = "pass";
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(input)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would never recommend just writing another piece of code your way to solve the question instead of a concrete explanation and an attempt to correct the present code.

Comment: It's not exactly another piece of code. It's OPs code changed; and only a minor change.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the array `args[]` which is not in the scope of the function `findAndPrint()`. You need to pass `args[0]` as an argument to the function call statement in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    findAndPrint(args[0], args[1]); //for report.txt
    findAndPrint(args[0], args[2]); //for address.txt
}
```

`args` is an argument of the main method. It is a String array that stores the individual command line inputs. In your case, the contents of the array `args[]` are = `{"ring", "reports.txt", "address.txt", "Homework.java"}`.

You can modify your `findAndPrint()` function in this way now:

```
static void findAndPrint(String wordToFind, String filename){
    Scanner fscan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    String str = "";
    while((str = fscan.nextLine()) != null){
        if(str.contains(wordToFind))
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added main arguments. I haven't ran the code, so that's on you to debug and test.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Code for E11.8. Searches all files specified on the command line and prints out all lines containing a specified word.
 * @Michael Goedken
 */
public class Find {
  /** Searches file for a word, prints out all lines containing that word.
  @param wordToFind the word to find
  @param filename the filename for the file to search
  */
  public static void findAndPrint(String wordToFind, String filename) {
   System.out.println(" File  " + filename);
   File one = new File(filename);
   Scanner in;
   try {
       in = new Scanner(one);
       while (in.hasNext()) {
           String line = in.nextLine();
           if (line.contains(wordToFind)) {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = args.length;
    if (length > 0 ) {
        String wordToFind = args[0];
        // now gather file names, bypassing first string
        for (int ii = 1; ii < length; ii++) {
            findAndPrint(wordToFind, args[ii]);         
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @progyammer, Did this solve your question?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work as a solution!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Code for E11.8. Searches all files specified on the command line and prints     out all lines     
   containing a specified word.
 * @Michael Goedken
 */
public class Find
{
   /**
   Searches file for a word, prints out all lines containing that word.
  @param wordToFind the word to find
  @param filename the filename for the file to search
   */
   public static void findAndPrint(String wordToFind, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));

   String input = wordToFind;
   while (in.hasNext()) 
   {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      if (line.contains(input)) 
      {
           System.out.println(line);
      }
   }
 }

/**
  First argument of the main method should be the word to be searched
  For other arguments of the main method, store the file names to be examined
*/
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  // call findAndPrint for each text file

   findAndPrint("tt", "/Users/MichaelGoedken/Desktop/mary.txt");

   findAndPrint("0", "/Users/MichaelGoedken/Desktop/transactions.txt");

  }
}
```